# Machine-readable APG III trees?

Tags: botany, taxonomy, phylogenetics

Does anyone know where I can find a machine-readable version of the phylogenetic trees from [APG III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APG_III_system)?  I'm looking for something that contains the full tree structure, including unnamed branches.  (i.e. not merely a list of which families are contained in which orders.)

The trees at the [APG III site](http://www.mobot.org/mobot/research/apweb/) are graphic images -- not easy to turn into a data structure.

Comment: Just email the curators. peter.stevens@mobot.org (Missouri Botanical Garden), or stevensp@umsl.edu (University of Missouri, St Louis)